# Why am getting an error cannot parse the key in google app engine for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I had tried with the below way and got failed,

```
Query query = new Query("Users");
List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(PAGE_SIZE));
for (Entity user : results){
Key key = user.getKey();
System.out.println(key); // here am getting as Users(151),Users(152)...
```

From here am passing the "Key" as request parameter to a servlet.

In My Servlet,

```
String keyString = req.getParameter("key");
Key key = KeyFactory.stringToKey(keyString);
datastore.delete(key);
```

the error says **"Cannot parse: Users(151)=="** and the line of error is " Key key = KeyFactory.stringToKey(keyString);"

Can anyone suggest me an idea,

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing `Key` as java objects to servlet, you should use this snippet to serialize

```
String encodedKey = KeyFactory.keyToString(key)
```

and this to deserialize

```
Key key = KeyFactory.stringToKey(encodedKey)
```

Comment: i got it now.. Thanks a lot. Can you clear me one doubt when i upload a file can i get the blob key output in JSON Format is it possible in google app engine for java

Comment: You can get it as a String via `blobKey.getKeyString()`: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobKey#getKeyString()

Comment: yes am already getting it as string but my requirement is to get as JSON and am not aware about whether it works or not can you give some link to get blobkeys as JSON

Comment: Just create JSON yourself: `"{'blobKey':'"+blobKey.getKeyString()+"'}"`